# Speed up API Post requests than curl?

Tags: bash, curl, ping, api

I am trying to make API post requests of JSON to a web server. This task needs to be asynchronous with least overhead. I am currently using CURL with infinite looping in bash and used '&' to make it asynch, which is slow for my task. How do I boost and reduce asynchronous API post task from CURL or without it? Are there any alternative tools that I can implement for this task?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

In particular when using `https`, opening the connection takes a measureable amount of time. If you do many requests, re-using the connection will make it faster.

Putting `curl` into the background with `&` just opens connections in parallel, it doesn't re-use an existing connection.

I do not know a tool that can re-use connections from the commandline.

However, you can do it e.g. with `libcurl`, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086609/how-to-do-keepalive-http-request-with-curl), and many other HTTP client libraries.

---

`libcurl` is a C library, so you need to write a C program to perform your API calls, instead of a shell script.

If C is not your thing, pick any other programming language you prefer, as written above.

In particular with `libcurl`, have a look at the example program under the link provided. Also read the `libcurl` docs and example programs (google). With the [easy libcurl interface](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html), the trick is to get a single [handle](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html), and then keep using that handle for all API calls - it will reuse the open connection.

Real concurrent operation will open several connections in parallel. Which may or may not make it faster - the bottleneck is usually the network, and not processing.

Comment: Since I am new to these concepts. Can you elaborate a little if I can implement asynchronous api post requests with libraries like libcurl?