# Asynchronous json post requests with cURL, minimize overhead?

Tags: bash, curl, ping, telnet, api

I think my method to make asynchronous post requests to API endpoint has some overhead. From [stackoverflow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663573/462342) I learned that libcurl is an alternative way but I am not familiar with libcurl and that with '&' i am opening a [new connection everytime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663573/462342) resulting overheads. I realized the keep-alive connection keeps the connection alive, still how do I make the json post request to api asynchronously and rapidly iterative, with very little overheads than my approach.

```
while :; do 
  curl -s 'https://test.com' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
  -H "X-XSRF-TOKEN: ${XSRF}" \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Chrome/92.0.4515.107' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'Origin: https://test.com' \
  -H 'Referer: https://test.com/user' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H "Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=${XSRF}" \
  --data-raw '{"name":"testUserName"}' \
  --compressed &
done
```

Comment: This script fires off an infinite number of identical HTTP requests in parallel, though your process quota will be exhausted quickly, which will lead to an infinite number of error messages. It's not clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: Consider python.    https://creativedata.stream/multi-threading-api-requests-in-python/

Comment: @steve is that the fastest way to handle this type of problem?

Comment: @steve Also, does that keep the connection alive so that saves some small time?

Comment: @berndbausch Yes sir, that is what I realized afterwards. I am actually trying to make asynchronous post requests, and solve the connection issue brought by above code which makes new connection every time by use of '&' there.

Comment: It's one of the fastest ways.  And it's far faster than continually spawning curl processes from a shell script.

Comment: Thanks @steve. I'll implement this solution. Is there any way I can make it happen in bash itself using curl or other libraries? Infact, what about nodejs fetch library, or python's asyncio in terms of performance?? Thanks again!!

Comment: Each time you launch a curl process, it creates a new connection. This has nothing to do with the `&`. In Linux/UNIX, [a child process can use a connection created by its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670891/is-there-a-way-for-multiple-processes-to-share-a-listening-socket), but I am not aware of a method for unrelated processes to share a connection. The relevant difference between Bash on one side and Node/Python on the other is the fact that most Bash commands are executed in their own process, whereas Node and Python code is executed in a single process.

Comment: In short, I doubt that Bash is the right tool for your requirement. As @steve commented, a Bash script is definitely not faster than a Node or Python program, because the overhead of launching processes is considerable (to which you have to add the overhead of the curl program to initialize itself each time it is launched).